# Rx Swift : Complex TextFields Validation

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm new to `RxSwift` and all example I found are handling simple cases.

I'm trying to do form validation for my textfields.
My custom TextField class has a method `isValid()` and a `regexp`. The `isValid` return is based on the `regexp` attribute.

So far, I have written the following :

```
let valids = [mLastName, mFirstName, mEmailField].map {
    $0.rx.text.map {
        text -> Bool in
        // I want more complex logic here
        // Like return field.isValid()
        return text!.characters.count > 0
    }
}    

let _ = Observable.combineLatest(valids) { iterator -> Bool in
    return iterator.reduce(true, { $0 && $1 })
}.subscribe(onNext: { allValid in
    ///update button according to AllValid
})
```

Does anyone know how to update the code to base the first `Observable<Bool>` be based on my `isValid()` method instead of `text!.characters.count`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer myself. The problem was in the first map, I shouldn't use anonymous parameter.

See :

```
let valids = [mLastName, mFirstName, mEmailField].map { field in
    field.rx.text.map({ _ in return field.isValid() })
}

_ = Observable.combineLatest(valids) { iterator -> Bool in
    return iterator.reduce(true, { return $0 && $1 })
}.bindTo(self.mValidateButton.rx.isEnabled)
```

Comment: How could you add to this to include whether two of the fields were matching (passwords)?

Comment: @LeeProbert depends if you want to check equality before or after rules conformance

Answer (score 6):

There are probably many ways to do that.

You can use `filter` to transform `rx.text` Observable in your custom TextField class:

```
var isTextValid: Observable<Bool> {
    return rx.text.filter { _ in 
        return self.isValid()
    }
}
```

then you can combine `isTextValid` from all text fields with `combineLatest`.

---

You can also extract the validation logic from the custom text field (maybe you don't even need a custom text field at all).

Benefits:

- validation could be easier to unit test
- you can easily reuse validation in different places in your app (e.g. for `UITextView` if you ever use it).

The draft of a validator class:

```
class TextValidator {
    var input: Observable<String>
    var regex: NSRegularExpression

    init(input: Observable<String>, regex: NSRegularExpression) {
       self.input = input
       self.regex = regex
    }

    func validate() -> Observable<Bool> {
        return input.map { text in 
             //return true if regex matches the text
        }
    }       
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
let mailValidator = TextValidator(input: mLastName.rx.text, regex: /* actual regex*/)
let firstNameValidator = TextValidator(input: mFirstName.rx.text, regex: ...)



let _ = Observable.combineLatest(mailValidator.validate(), firstName.validate(), ...) 
// and so on
```

Now if you want to write unit tests for the validators (which you probably should do), you can simply pass `Observable.just("Some value")` as `input` to `TextValidator` and verify what Observable returned by `validate()` does.